# compiling java source in oracle 19

Tags: java, oracle

Our application migrated/upgrated to azure and from oracle 11 to oracle 19.  we have a java class in our code and  am not able to compile them in oracle 19.

here is the code is 11 version. please help me out with this.

```java
Create or replace
and compile java source named "DirList"
as
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DirList
{
   public static void getList(String in_dir_name)
                   throws SQLException
   {
      String os_directory;
      #sql {Select directory_path into :os_directory from all_directories where directory_name = upper(:in_dir_name)};

      File path = new File( os_directory );
      String[] list = path.list();
      String element;

      for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      {
         element = list[i];
         #sql { INSERT INTO mra_dir_list (FILENAME) VALUES (:element) };
      }
   }

}
```

```
-------------------------------------------------

Warning: Java created with compilation errors.

SYS@u7uvm1d1:SQL>
SYS@u7uvm1d1:SQL> show errors;
Errors for JAVA SOURCE "DirList":

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      DirList:10: error: illegal character: '#'
0/0      21 errors
0/0      ^
0/0      DirList:10: error: not a statement
0/0      #sql {Select directory_path into :os_directory from
         all_directories where directory_name = upper(:in_dir_name)};

0/0      ^
0/0      DirList:10: error: ';' expected
0/0      #sql {Select directory_path into :os_directory from
         all_directories where directory_name = upper(:in_dir_name)};
```

Comment: Well, it's telling you the # is illegal, so what is `#sql` supposed to do? Is that something a preprocessor is supposed to handle, maybe?

Comment: @AlexPoole That is [SQLJ](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chthree.htm#CACEJBBC). According to the docs it needs a translator (pre-compiler) to convert it to standard Java souce code. I'm guessing that that is something additional to the basic installation and its not something that is installed on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

You code is using [SQLJ](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chthree.htm#CACEJBBC) and the error message is telling you that Java does not recognise the SQLJ `#sql{ ... }` syntax.

Either:

1. Install SQLJ into your Azure environment; or
2. Convert the SQLJ code to standard JDBC code.

Comment: To add on to this answer, SQLJ was desupported in Oracle 12.2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/desupported-features-oracle-database-12c-r2.html#GUID-219C5674-6F2C-4051-A61B-919DA4FF3CB6